# Set all new text in UITextView to bold

Tags: ios, objective-c, attributes, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` which is currently using the System default font. After the user presses the bold button, I want all the new text that gets typed to be in bold but the previous text to stay the way it was. I'm currently using the `attributedText` property to change other properties as well (color, size, etc.) so I would like to maintain whatever properties there were before, other than font.

I've tried setting the `textView` font to bold but that changes all the text. Any advice?

Comment: you need to apply different fonts to different parts of text using NSRange in addAttribte:value:range method of NSAttributedString

Comment: @Puneet But if the range is constantly changing, how can I do this?

Comment: You need to make the rangedynamic. You have sapme old text. based on its length, you can know the location of the new typed text and make range accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [RKRichTextView](https://github.com/fs/RKRichTextView). I am sure this will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `[textView setTypingAttributes]` in Objc or `textView.typingAttributes` in Swift